# How do I load iframe in the div inside the div with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery

My div is

```
<div id="chatMessageArea" class="divBorder">
    <div id="messageArea" class="divBorder"></div>
    <div id="enterMessage" class="divBorder"></div>
</div>
```

How to load the new Iframe in the div having id `messageArea`.

My Jquery function will be,

```
function createIframe(intxnId){

    var iframe = "<iframe id='ch_"+intxnId+"' src='" + contexPath + "/heartChat.jsp' ></iframe>";
    alert("iFrame Details : "+iframe);
    ("#chatMessageArea").find("messageArea").append(iframe);
}
```

My alert result is ,

[image]

And I  got the error as,

`Object doesnot support this error` in this line `("#chatMessageArea").find("messageArea").append(iframe);`.

How can I create the IFrame with the JSP in the inside div with the ID of `messageArea`.

Comment: you are just missing the $  in your jquery call !aren't you ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off to start with, but you can directly select the `messageArea` using it's `id`, like this:

```
$("#messageArea").append(iframe);
```

---

Just to clear up your original problem, you are missing the starting `$` and also the `#` from your `messageArea` selector, so it should have been this:

```
$("#chatMessageArea").find("#messageArea").append(iframe);
```

but again, the `find` is pointless as you already have a unique ID for `messageArea` (or at least it should be unique!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function createIframe(intxnId){
    // using $() to create the DOM object
    var iframe = $("<iframe id='ch_"+intxnId+"' src='" + contexPath + "/heartChat.jsp' ></iframe>");  
    alert("iFrame Details : "+iframe);
    // You have to add the '#' to search for an ID instead of an tagname
    $("#chatMessageArea").find("#messageArea").append(iframe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a $ from the start of the last line:
    $("#chatMessageArea").find("messageArea").append(iframe);

Comment: yes a bit too slow :) however, you also have a problem with your `find` selector and your formatting - please format code so it displays in this post correctly (use the button, or indent it by 4 spaces)